# Combining/merging data classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Is there a way to merge kotlin data classes without specifying all the properties?

```
data class MyDataClass(val prop1: String, val prop2: Int, ...//many props)
```

with a function with the following signature:

```
fun merge(left: MyDataClass, right: MyDataClass): MyDataClass
```

where this function checks each property on both classes and where they are different uses the left parameter to create a new MyDataClass.

Is this possible possible using kotlin-reflect, or some other means?

EDIT: more clarity

Here is a better description of what i want to be able to do

```
  data class Bob(
        val name: String?,
        val age: Int?,
        val remoteId: String?,
        val id: String)

@Test
fun bob(){

    val original = Bob(id = "local_id", name = null, age = null, remoteId = null)
    val withName = original.copy(name = "Ben")
    val withAge = original.copy(age = 1)
    val withRemoteId = original.copy(remoteId = "remote_id")

    //TODO: merge without accessing all properties
    // val result = 
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(Bob(id = "local_id", name = "Ben", age=1, remoteId = "remote_id"))
}
```

Comment: So in the new instance, you want to keep the property values that are the same in `left` and `right`, and for the ones that aren't, you want to use the property values from `left`?

Comment: @zsmb13 yep that is correct

Comment: Is this any different than making a copy of `left`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
infix fun <T : Any> T.merge(mapping: KProperty1<T, *>.() -> Any?): T {
    //data class always has primary constructor ---v
    val constructor = this::class.primaryConstructor!!
    //calculate the property order
    val order = constructor.parameters.mapIndexed { index, it -> it.name to index }
                                      .associate { it };

    // merge properties
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val merged = (this::class as KClass<T>).declaredMemberProperties
                                           .sortedWith(compareBy{ order[it.name]})
                                           .map { it.mapping() }
                                           .toTypedArray()


    return constructor.call(*merged);
}
```

### Edit

```
infix fun <T : Any> T.merge(right: T): T {
    val left = this;
    return left merge mapping@ {
        //    v--- implement your own merge strategy
        return@mapping this.get(left) ?: this.get(right);
    };
}
```

### Example

```
val original = Bob(id = "local_id", name = null, age = null, remoteId = null)
val withName = original.copy(name = "Ben")
val withAge = original.copy(age = 1)
val withRemoteId = original.copy(remoteId = "remote_id")

val result = withName merge withAge merge withRemoteId;
```

Comment: This is really good, but doesnt work as get an illegal arument exception in the case of: `data class Bob(val name: String?,val age: Int?,val id: String)` because memberProperties comes back in the order or age, id name which is the wrong order for the constructor and consequently blows up in the construction!

Comment: `infix fun <T : Any> T.merge(mapping: KProperty1<T, *>.() -> Any?): T {
    val kClass = this::class as KClass<T>
    
    val constructorParameters = kClass.primaryConstructor!!.parameters
    val props = kClass.memberProperties

    val merged: Array<Any?> = constructorParameters.map { cParam ->
        props.find { it.name == cParam.name }?.mapping()
    }.toTypedArray()
    
    return this::class.primaryConstructor!!.call(*merged);
}` 

This seems to have fixed my problem. Although not sure how viable this is as a solution in terms of performance @holi-java

Comment: @BenFlowers sir, how about it now?

Comment: Thanks for this. I also had to add .filter { order.containsKey(it.name) } on the declaredMemberProperties since I have one property which is not part of the constructor.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to copy values from the right when values in the left are `null` then you can do the following:

```
inline infix fun <reified T : Any> T.merge(other: T): T {
    val propertiesByName = T::class.declaredMemberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
    val primaryConstructor = T::class.primaryConstructor
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("merge type must have a primary constructor")
    val args = primaryConstructor.parameters.associateWith { parameter ->
        val property = propertiesByName[parameter.name]
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("no declared member property found with name '${parameter.name}'")
        (property.get(this) ?: property.get(other))
    }
    return primaryConstructor.callBy(args)
}
```

Usage:

```
data class MyDataClass(val prop1: String?, val prop2: Int?)
val a = MyDataClass(null, 1)
val b = MyDataClass("b", 2)
val c = a merge b // MyDataClass(prop1=b, prop2=1)
```

Comment: This can also be used with non-data classes, if the primary constructor includes the fields you want to merge.

Comment: @AbhiMuktheeswarar this solution does rely on reflection so proguard won't find any static references in the code to some of these members, you'll need to find which members are not available and then instruct proguard to not strip those.

Comment: Maybe I should have commented properly. It doesn't work (NullPointerException) - at least in my case with r8 enabled. After removing the force unwrap of nullable variables & making the return type as nullable. It was working.

Comment: Those forced unwraps are dangerous. Bound to lead to null pointer exceptions

Comment: @Inn0vative1 can you elaborate? I'm guessing you are referring to the `!!`. A `data class` will always have a `primaryConstructor` and the code only looks up properties by their names  so I think both `!!` are "safe". There may certainly be a better way to write this though these days possibly leverage more recent additions to Kotlin too.

Comment: @mfulton26 if you can an improve your answer it would be great. I am also facing a similar issue with proguard.

Comment: I've attempted to improve the code by throwing specific errors instead of using `!!` but in order for a merge to work there 1) must be a primary constructor present on the type and 2) property lookups must work as expected. From what I understand all parameters on the primary constructor of a `data class` `constructor` should also be `declaredMemberProperties` on the `data class` itself, if this is not the case then merging cannot be done. I may be missing something. I am open to more feedback/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: at building time it says Unresolved reference: declaredMemberProperties but I can see that the method should be present also in the documentation. any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: @PedroTeran you will need `kotlin-reflect` on your classpath, that or something similar could be the issue

Answer (score 3):

A class-specific way to combine data classes when we can define the fields we want to combine would be:

```
data class SomeData(val dataA: Int?, val dataB: String?, val dataC: Boolean?) {
    fun combine(newData: SomeData): SomeData {        
        //Let values of new data replace corresponding values of this instance, otherwise fall back on the current values.
        return this.copy(dataA = newData.dataA ?: dataA,
                dataB = newData.dataB ?: dataB,
                dataC = newData.dataC ?: dataC)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@mfulton26's solution merges properties that are part of primary constructor only. I have extended that to support all properties

```
inline infix fun <reified T : Any> T.merge(other: T): T {
    val nameToProperty = T::class.declaredMemberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
    val primaryConstructor = T::class.primaryConstructor!!
    val args = primaryConstructor.parameters.associate { parameter ->
        val property = nameToProperty[parameter.name]!!
        parameter to (property.get(other) ?: property.get(this))
    }
    val mergedObject = primaryConstructor.callBy(args)
    nameToProperty.values.forEach { it ->
        run {
            val property = it as KMutableProperty<*>
            val value = property.javaGetter!!.invoke(other) ?: property.javaGetter!!.invoke(this)
            property.javaSetter!!.invoke(mergedObject, value)
        }
    }
    return mergedObject
}
```

Comment: This Code not marge class inside a class marge.

I was hoping this would work with let's call them deep classes?
data class Some(val a: String?, val b: String?)
data class Other(val some: Some?, val c: String?, val d: String?)

when i do Other(Some("a", null), "c", null).merge(Other(Some(null, "b"), null, "d))
I'd expect to get Other(Some("a", "b"), "c", "d")