# Deep merging data classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, data-class

How can I do a recursive / deep merge of two data classes in Kotlin? Something like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.*
import kotlin.reflect.full.*

data class Address(
  val street: String? = null,
  val zip: String? = null
)

data class User(
  val name: String? = null,
  val age: Int? = null,
  val address: Address? = null
)

inline fun <reified T : Any> T.merge(other: T): T {
  val nameToProperty = T::class.declaredMemberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
  val primaryConstructor = T::class.primaryConstructor!!
  val args = primaryConstructor.parameters.associate { parameter ->
    val property = nameToProperty[parameter.name]!!
    val type = property.returnType.classifier as KClass<*>
    if (type.isData) {
      parameter to this.merge(other) //inline function can't be recursive
    } else {
      parameter to (property.get(other) ?: property.get(this))
    }
  }
  return primaryConstructor.callBy(args)
}

val u1 = User(name = "Tiina", address = Address(street = "Hämeenkatu"))
val u2 = User(age = 23, address = Address(zip = "33100"))

u1.merge(u2)
// expected: User(age = 23, name= "Tiina", address = Address(zip = "33100", street = "Hämeenkatu")
```

related: [Combining/merging data classes in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566607/combining-merging-data-classes-in-kotlin)

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by deep merge? What do you expect to happen if u1 and u2 both define a name? Should it take the name of u1 or u2?

Comment: Secondly, do you really need to make a generic "deep merge" (i.e. one that will work for all data types?). If you really ask yourself "do I need this super generalized solution right now?" the answer will most likely be no. If you really do need a generalized solution that will deep merge 2 objects then it does look like you are going down a somewhat sensible route.

Comment: In case of both have a field defined, the last non-null wins. Nested data classes should be merged recursively. The data class hierarchies are deep in my case, so not looking for doing that manually, need a generic solution. Coming from Clojure, here's a dynamic deep-merge: https://github.com/weavejester/medley/blob/master/src/medley/core.cljc#L213-L234

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were several problems in the posted code,

1. unnecessary reification and inlining
2. when type isData was detected instead of merging the values of the property merge on `this` with the `other` was called, so it became endless recursion.
3. `get` cannot be used on KProperty1<out T, Any?> because of the variance
4. some non-idiomatic stuff which works, but can be made better

Here's the fixed version. For production I would've added some checks and error messages, but this should work for "happy path" and hopefully give you the base to build on:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.KParameter
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties
import kotlin.reflect.full.isSubclassOf
import kotlin.reflect.full.primaryConstructor

data class Address(
    val street: String? = null,
    val zip: String? = null
)

data class User(
    val name: String? = null,
    val age: Int? = null,
    val address: Address? = null,
    val map: Map<String, Int>? = null
)

fun <T> mergeData(property: KProperty1<out T, Any?>, left: T, right: T): Any? {
    val leftValue = property.getter.call(left)
    val rightValue = property.getter.call(right)
    return rightValue?.let {
        if ((property.returnType.classifier as KClass<*>).isSubclassOf(Map::class)) (leftValue as? Map<*, *>)?.plus(it as Map<*, *>)
        else leftValue?.merge(it)
    } ?: rightValue ?: leftValue
}

fun <T> lastNonNull(property: KProperty1<out T, Any?>, left: T, right: T) =
    property.getter.call(right) ?: property.getter.call(left)

fun <T : Any> T.merge(other: T): T {
    val nameToProperty = this::class.declaredMemberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
    val primaryConstructor = this::class.primaryConstructor!!
    val args: Map<KParameter, Any?> = primaryConstructor.parameters.associateWith { parameter ->
        val property = nameToProperty[parameter.name]!!
        val type = property.returnType.classifier as KClass<*>
        when {
            type.isData || type.isSubclassOf(Map::class) -> mergeData(property, this, other)
            else -> lastNonNull(property, this, other)
        }
    }
    return primaryConstructor.callBy(args)
}


// verification

val u1 = User(name = "Tiina", address = Address(street = "Hämeenkatu"), map = mapOf("a" to 1))
val u2 = User(age = 23, address = Address(zip = "33100"), map = mapOf("b" to 2))

check(
    u1.merge(u2) == User(
        age = 23,
        name = "Tiina",
        address = Address(zip = "33100", street = "Hämeenkatu"),
        map = mapOf("a" to 1,"b" to 2)
    )
) {
    "doesn't work"
}

println("Works!")
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! much simpler and works. One comment: the last line in `mergeValues` should probably be:

```
return rightValue?.let { r -> leftValue?.let { l -> r.merge(l)) } ?: r } ?: leftValue
```

so that we use the non-null value here too. If you think that's correct, could you update the example for future seekers?

Comment: Right you are, I missed that case. Updated the code, although a bit differently than suggested—for better readability. It is advisable to avoid nesting scoping functions too much. Improves readability and reduces probability of mistakes during refactoring. And I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Great solution. I was hoping though this would work with maps but it doesn't. 
`data class User(val name: String? = null, val items: Map<String, Int>? = null)`
`User(items = mapOf("monitor" to 1))`
`User(name = "George", items = mapOf("laptop" to 2))`

Comment: @EmanuelGeorgeHategan supporting maps is a trivial addition here, I've updated the answer to showcase that as well.